# Problem with Cosets in the proving of $K/H \trianglelefteq G/H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

We have $H \trianglelefteq G$ and $H \subseteq K \leq G$.
we can prove if $K \trianglelefteq G$ then $K/H \trianglelefteq G/H$ like this:

We already showed that $K/H \leq G/H$. If we show that $\forall Hg \in G/H$ and $\forall Hx \in K/H$ : $(Hg)^{-1}(Hx)(Hg) \in K/H$ then the proof is complete. we have that $Hg \in G/H \Rightarrow g \in G$ and $Hx \in K/H = \{Ht | t \in K\} \Rightarrow \exists t \in K$ such that $Hx = Ht$.
$\begin{align*}
g \in G, t \in K & \ \ \Longrightarrow  \ \ g^{-1}tg \in K \\
& \ \ \Longrightarrow  \ \  H(g^{-1}tg) \in K/H \\
& \ \ \Longrightarrow  \ \ (Hg^{-1}) (Ht)(Hg) \in K/H\\
& \ \ \Longrightarrow  \ \ (Hg)^{-1} (Ht)(Hg) \in K/H\\
\end{align*}$

I can't undestand this part of proof

> $Hx \in K/H = \{Ht | t \in K\} \Rightarrow \exists t \in K$ such that
>   $Hx = Ht$

why we use $t$ ? can't we continue with $x$ and say $Hx \in K/H \Rightarrow x \in K$ ?

Comment: A shorter proof: $K/H$ is the kernel of the obvious homomoprhism $G/H\to G/K$.

Comment: I believe we could've kept the $x$ and not bothered with $t$, yes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo. $x\in K/H$ so it should say $\exists t\in K\;(x=H t)$.

Comment: The op said he did not understand a part of the proof .I couldn't understand it either until I saw that it didn't make sense because of a typo. If the typo is the reason that the OP couldn't understand it, then that is the answer.It certainly looks like it to me. He asks why we don't let $x\in K$ and delete $t$. Well we can't  because $x$ is not in $K$ . It's in $ K/H$....This is in response to a moderator's criticism of my A.